# setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build in Flutter

Tags: flutter

in my Todo App list, I'm trying to make the global state in my task list view but I'm facing some issues. I'm using StatefulWidget and StatelessWidget. In StatelessWidget Checkbox onChanged I want to toggle the Checkbox value and comes from the parent Widget but it's showing some setState() build issue Please have a look If you can.

`tasks_lists.dart`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TasksList extends StatefulWidget {
  const TasksList({super.key});

  @override
  State<TasksList> createState() => _TasksListState();
}

class _TasksListState extends State<TasksList> {
  bool isChecked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        'List 1',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          decoration:
              isChecked ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : TextDecoration.none,
        ),
      ),
      trailing: TaskCheckbox(
        checkBoxState: isChecked,
        toggleCheckboxState: (bool checkedBoxState) {
          setState(
            () {
              isChecked = checkedBoxState;
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TaskCheckbox extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool checkBoxState;
  final Function? toggleCheckboxState;

  const TaskCheckbox({
    super.key,
    required this.checkBoxState,
    this.toggleCheckboxState,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Checkbox(
      value: checkBoxState,
      onChanged: toggleCheckboxState!(checkBoxState),
      activeColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
      ),
      side: MaterialStateBorderSide.resolveWith(
        (states) => BorderSide(
          width: 2.0,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This means that the function is called during build,

```
onChanged: toggleCheckboxState!(checkBoxState),
```

while this calls the function when `Checkbox` is tapped.

```
onChanged: (checkBoxState) => toggleCheckboxState!(checkBoxState),
```

Take a look of [Introduction to widgets](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets-intro).

Answer (score 1):

Your `toggleCheckboxState` function call during building the UI, so you need to put it inside `addPostFrameCallback` so it run after UI builds, like this:

```
toggleCheckboxState: (bool checkedBoxState) {

   WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
       setState(
         () {
           isChecked = checkedBoxState;
         },
       );  
   });
          
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing value/state so you have to make **TaskCheckbox** a Stateful widget.

Comment: No works to change stateful

Answer (score 0):

onChange is a `Fuction(bool)`. try to change TaskCheckbox to this:

```
class TaskCheckbox extends StatelessWidget {
 final bool checkBoxState;
  final Function(bool)? toggleCheckboxState;

  const TaskCheckbox({
    super.key,
    required this.checkBoxState,
    this.toggleCheckboxState,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Checkbox(
      value: checkBoxState,
      onChanged: toggleCheckboxState!,
      activeColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
      ),
      side: MaterialStateBorderSide.resolveWith(
            (states) => BorderSide(
          width: 2.0,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Not Works......

Comment: are you sure? but it is working fine for me. you don't need to change stateless to stateful it is just onChange accepts Function(bool) not function.

Comment: you need just change Function? to Function(bool)? to return the result and because toggleCheckboxState is Function(bool)? just pass it to onChange. just this will solve your problem,(try to flutter clean and flutter pub get maybe changes not happend)